# Material Icons: Scaling 48dp to 144dp limitations

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-drawable, gimp

I'm trying to use the [ic_library_books_black_48dp](https://material.io/icons/#ic_library_books) [**Material Icon**](https://material.io/icons/) as a file-type icon in a file-listing view.

The largest available file, **ic_library_books_black_48dp.png**, comes in the following densities

```
drawable-mdpi 
drawable-hpi 
drawable-xhdpi 
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

Because image-file types display a thumbnail preview, larger icons are required for consistency. They were adjusted to *144x144 dp*:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_iv"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"/>
```

Here is a zoomed in view of a prototype on an **xhdpi device**:

[image: File listing view]
**note**: zoom in browser to see pixelation differences.

I wasn't happy with the provided xhdpi resolution, so I made copies of the xxhdpi and xxxhdpi versions, renamed them accordingly, and put them into **drawable-xhdpi** folder

```
resources
    drawable-xhdpi
        ic_library_books_black_48dp.png
        ic_library_books_black_48dp_xxhdpi.png
        ic_library_books_black_48dp_xxxhdpi.png
```

They were then assigned in **`GetView()`**

```
switch (fileType)
{
    case AttachmentFileType.FileType.Docs:
        iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_library_books_black_48dp);
        break;
    case AttachmentFileType.FileType.Audio:
        iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_library_books_black_48dp_xxhdpi);
        break;
    case AttachmentFileType.FileType.Images:
        iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_library_books_black_48dp_xxxhdpi);
        break;
    default:
        iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_attachment_test);
        break;
}
```

**I prefer the clarity of ic_library_books_black_48dp_xxxhdpi.png scaled up to 144x144 dp on my xhdp device.** However, this approach will not work on higher density screens (xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) because xxxhdpi is the highest provided version of the ic_library_books_black_48dp.png. To support xxhdpi and xxxhdpi I would need a xxxxhdpi and xxxxxhdpi version of icon (ie, "two grades higher"), respectively. **Is there a way to make this work without resulting to creating custom icons (can android studio or maybe an editing program upscale while maintaining pixel density)?**

Comment: Have you tried using Vector Icons? you don’t specify your API version requirements, but I’d read about that and use it.

Comment: I've read about them briefly. I need to support marshmallow.

Comment: So that's what the .svg file was, nice (5.0 / api 21 min for vector).

Comment: See my answer for further info ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, I’d use vector graphics. They are supported right from Android Studio.

`File -> New -> Vector Graphic`.

Then tap the Icon to “search”… find your Library Book icon…

[image: Library Books]

Next and finish it. (don’t need to change anything here).

If you’re above API 21, then you’re good to go, you can reference it like any other icon.

If you need support to lower APIs, read [the official Android Documentation about Vector Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html).

Additionally, read all about [Android Studio support here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html).

Answer (score 2):

a tricky way is set scaleType of imageView to fitcenter and set constant width=144dp and height=144dp to your imageview. it will scale up your icon to 144dp

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_library_books_black_48dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use scaleType  of imageView to FIT_CENTER.
FIT_CENTER-Scale the image using CENTER. 
in XML file

```
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or in your Activity class

```
 imgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```